Intuition for 'create coequalizers of U-split pairs'
I'm using Emily Rhiel's notation in her book Category Theory in Context.

A functor $U: D\to C$ is said to create coequalizers of $U$-split pairs if any $U$-split coequalizer admits a coequalizer in $D$ whose image under $U$ is isomorphic to the fork underlying the given $U$-split coequalizer diagram in $C$, and if any such fork in $D$ is a coequalizer.

There are many theorems/propositions that requires this definition, e.g.

A right adjoint functor $U$ is monadic iff it creates coequalizers of $U$-split pairs.

I can't even get the point of this weird definition, my questions are:

What does it mean to say 'isomorphic to the fork...'? is it simply a new fork that is isomorphic to the previous one in corresponding position or do we need some commutativity? what about the arrows?

I think this is saying that if $f,g:A\to B$ are parallel arrows and its image under $U$ have coeq $UA\rightrightarrows UB\xrightarrow{h} C$, then we can lift this to some fork $A\rightrightarrows B\xrightarrow{p} X$ s.t. $U(h)=p,U(X)=C$, and moreover this fork is coeq. Am I understanding correctly?

Why is this definition mentioned? In my view this is a weird definition with no any intuition, (unlike creation of limits). Can you give a simple example to show its necessarity or its power, and why the monadicity relies on this condition so much?


It is what is needed to make the monadicity theorem true – nothing more, nothing less. You could deduce it yourself like solving a system of equations: replace the condition with some property $P$, try to prove the theorem, then figure out what $P$ must be. Or you can just prove a weaker theorem (“if” instead of “if and only if”) with a looser condition.
